# How to center Matplotlib text legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, multiline

I have a plot with a legend. Its title has multiple lines like so

[image: plot with legend]

created by this code:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot()
legend = ax.legend(title="Line 1 is short\nLine 2 is slightly longer")
plt.show()
```

I would like the individual lines of the legend title to be centered. How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding this will do the job:

```
legend.get_title().set_multialignment('center')
```